# FastApi Sqlalchemy sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm new to the sqlalchemy.
I was trying to do a simple insert.
But I get an InvalidRequestError.

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance '<Block
> at 0x2464fd85670>'

It seems like there is something wrong with the refresh().
Any advice would be greatful.
Below is my code.

```
@router.post("/{user_id}")
async def block(
        user_id: int,
        session: Session = Depends(get_db_session),
        user: UserDB = Depends(get_current_user)):
    block = BlockCreate(blocker=user.id, blocked=user_id)
    db_block = db_models.Block(**block.dict())
    session.add(db_block)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(db_block)
    return {"block": db_block}

class BlockBase(BaseModel):
    blocker: int
    blocked: int


class BlockCreate(BlockBase):
    pass
```

### DB setting

```
class Block(Base):
    __tablename__ = "block"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    blocker = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    blocked = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: The error means that the primary key of `db_block` no longer exists in the database.  By itself this code looks fine, so there must be something else going on in you code or environment.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I found out that it inserts null to the id column. But I don't know why. Sometimes the autoincrement doesn't work.